# ckeditor issue while ajax submit

Tags: ajax, wysiwyg

i m using ckeditor in a form that submits through ajax. when the submit is clicked and the submission is in progress my ckeditor converts into a plain text editor and all the controls are gone, as soon as the submit is complete, the controls are back, it looks ugly. Any solution?

Comment: any thoughts to solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

though the solution looks temporary but i see no bugs in it. The solution is to comment the line:

```
CKEDITOR.instances[textarea_id].destroy(true);
```

under ckeditor.utils.js

More better option would be to put a condition to skip the destruction of ckeditor instance

Comment: Not necessary anymore since the issue is absent in recent versions of module [ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) – tested with Drupal Core Image fields, which submit via AJAX. But you pointed me into the right solution for a related issue :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying CKEditor via the new [editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor) module (not via [ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) as in the original question) and experience this issue, then it is due to [Drupal issue #2691101](https://www.drupal.org/node/2691101). See there for a patch that solves it.